# How can I see the plain text version of a MIME email?

Tags: email, mime-types

I'm building an App that will send HTML emails. I compose MIME formatted email. I want to test both versions of the content (Html and Plain text) :  Is there a way to see the plain/text version of the emails I send with my code? Is this possible to make Outlook, Thunderbird, Mail or any other Email Client App, not displaying the HTML part, but the plain text version instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MacOS Mail.app to see the various representations (there can be more than just the HTML and plain ones) choose from the menu View->Message->Plain Text Alternative (or more generally Previous Alternative) From that sub menu you can also choose to see Raw text which is the email without decoding the MIME parts.